# How to make an R heatmap that fills up a PNG image (no background)

Tags: r, png, heatmap

I want to explicitly set the pixel size of a heatmap to the number of rows and columns being plotted (actually it's a multiple of that, e.g. here 15 square pixels per point). But no matter what I try, I get an annoying background.

```
data = as.matrix(datasets::crimtab)
png(filename = "foo.png", width = dim(data)[1]*15, height = dim(data)[2]*15)
heatmap(data, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, labRow=FALSE, labCol=FALSE, scale="row",
        margins = c(0, 0), useRaster=TRUE, mai=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(0,0,0,0),
        bty="n", oma=c(0,0,0,0), omi=c(0,0,0,0), pty="m", plt=c(0,1,0,1), 
        mgp=c(0,0,0), ann=FALSE, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
dev.off()
```

I tried with and without a separate `par()` call.

```
png(filename = "bar.png", width = dim(data)[1]*15, height = dim(data)[2]*15)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(0,0,0,0),
    bty="n", oma=c(0,0,0,0), omi=c(0,0,0,0), pty="m", plt=c(0,1,0,1), 
    mgp=c(0,0,0), ann=FALSE, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
heatmap(data, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, labRow=FALSE, labCol=FALSE, scale="row",
        margins = c(0, 0), useRaster=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

I don't know if it's possible to do an R fiddle with the png device.